# Limit of Integral over Any Measurable Subset Exists

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation

> Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of nonnegative measurable functions on $\Bbb{R}$ that converges pointwise on $\Bbb{R}$ to $f$ and $f$ be integrable over $\Bbb{R}$. Show that $$\mbox{If } \int_\Bbb{R} f = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_\Bbb{R} f_n, \mbox{ then } \int_E f = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_E f_n$$
>   for any measurable set $E \subseteq \Bbb{R}$.

I found a solution to this problem [here](http://www2.math.umd.edu/~punshs/Analysis-Solutions/HW5-Sol.pdf) (see the third and fourth pages), but I don't understand the following line from the proof:

> $$\int_{\Bbb{R} - E} f \le \liminf_{n} \int_{\Bbb{R} - E} f_n = \int_\Bbb{R}f - \limsup_n \int_E f_n$$

Is the equality valid? The only way I could see to justify this step was by noting that $\int_\Bbb{R} f_n = \int_E f_n + \int_{\Bbb{R} - E} f_n$ or $\int_{\Bbb{R} - E} f_n = \int_{\Bbb{R}} f_n - \int_E f_n$, and then

$$\liminf_{n} \int_{\Bbb{R} - E} f_n = \liminf_n (\int_{\Bbb{R}} f_n - \int_E f_n) = \int_\Bbb{R} f - \limsup_n \int_E f_n$$

But would this not be fallacious, as we do not know whether the $f_n$ are integrable and therefore cannot subtract those integrals, which are potentially infinite, as we see fit? Is this solution incorrect, or am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$f_n$ is integrable for $n$ large enough, because we have the assumption
$$\int f = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \int f_n.$$
It works in the following way: The convergence gives you an $n_0$, such that for every $n\geq n_0$
$$\int f_n \leq  1+\int f  < \infty.$$
Since $f_n$ is nonnegativ, it is integrable.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the link to the proof from the original post no longer works. For the sake of having full context (and for those who are curious), here is a proof to the problem OP is referencing.

By assumption, $\int_{\mathbb{R}}^{}fd\mu=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}}^{}f_nd\mu$, which means that if $f$ is integrable, $f_n$ is also integrable for large enough $n$.
(See answer by humanStampedist)

Next, let $E$ be any subset of $\mathbb{R}$.
$\mathbb{R}$ can be decomposed into disjoint sets $\mathbb{R}=E\cup(\mathbb{R}\setminus E)$.

By Fatou's Lemma, we can claim
\begin{align}
    \int_{\mathbb{R}\setminus E}^{}\liminf_nf_n&\leq\liminf_n\int_{\mathbb{R}\setminus E}^{}f_n\nonumber\\
    \implies\int_{\mathbb{R}\setminus E}^{}f&\leq\liminf_n\int_{\mathbb{R}\setminus E}^{}f_n
\end{align}
where the second line follows from pointwise convergence of $f_n$ to $f$.
Using integration over disjoint sets, we can write
\begin{align}
    \liminf_n\int_{\mathbb{R}\setminus E}^{}f_n&=\liminf_n\int_{\mathbb{R}}^{}f_n-\limsup_n\int_{E}^{}f_n\nonumber\\
    &=\int_{\mathbb{R}}^{}f-\limsup_n\int_{E}^{}f_n
\end{align}
where the second line follows from the assumption that $\int_{\mathbb{R}}^{}fd\mu=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}}^{}f_nd\mu$
Rearranging the above results yields
\begin{align}
    \int_{\mathbb{R}\setminus E}^{}f&\leq\int_{\mathbb{R}}^{}f-\limsup_n\int_{E}^{}f_n\nonumber\\
    \implies\limsup_n\int_{E}^{}f_n&\leq\int_{\mathbb{R}}^{}f-\int_{\mathbb{R}\setminus E}^{}f\nonumber\\
    \implies\limsup_n\int_{E}^{}f_n&\leq\int_{E}^{}f
\end{align}
By again using Fatou's Lemma, we know
\begin{equation}
    \int_{E}^{}f\leq\liminf_n\int_{E}^{}f_n
\end{equation}
The only way for $\limsup_n\int_{E}^{}f_n\leq\int_{E}^{}f$ and $\int_{E}^{}f\leq\liminf_n\int_{E}^{}f_n$ to simultaneously be true is if we have equality to the limit.
Thus
\begin{equation}\label{eqn:P2a5}
    \lim_n\int_{E}^{}f_n=\int_{E}^{}f
\end{equation}