# $\liminf (f_n+g_n)=\liminf f_n + \liminf g_n$

Tags: supremum-and-infimum, limsup-and-liminf, sequence-of-function

In two different solutions I see people use the principle that $\liminf (f_n+g_n)=\liminf f_n + \liminf g_n$.

[Showing $\int_E f=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_E f_n$ for all measurable $E$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1212418/showing-int-e-f-lim-n-to-infty-int-e-f-n-for-all-measurable-e?rq=1)

[Limit of Integral over Any Measurable Subset Exists](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2713141/limit-of-integral-over-any-measurable-subset-exists)

However, I thought this was supposed to be an inequality rather than an equality.  That is to say, I thought that we could only say

$$\liminf(f_n+g_n)\ge \liminf f_n + \liminf g_n$$

We do have that $f_n$ is nonnegative and $g_n$ is nonpositive, but I don't know how this would make the principle valid.  Am I misunderstanding something, or is there a special condition being met which ensures equality?

Comment: It's pretty intuitively an inequality, as they would only be equal if the functions had their "smallest" values at the same points in the domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right; it's only an inequality; for instance, take $f_n=(-1)^n$ and $g_n=(-1)^{n-1}$. Note that, in the second of the questions to which you have posted a link, one of the sequences converges, and, in that case, we have an equality. I don't see the equality in the first question.